Existing Platforms and (AI) Solutions for Remote Research Support (Grant Management, ...)
Background:
I'm part of an organization that provides support to remote researchers through a fellowship program. Our current model includes:

Providing management feedback and guidance to researchers
Connecting researchers with technical experts for paper review and feedback
Assisting with grant identification and application processes
Supporting researchers in developing independence in their research careers
Operating on a non-profit basis, primarily through grant funding

Question:
I'm interested in learning about existing solutions or platforms that might serve similar purposes:

Are there established platforms that:

Connect remote researchers working on specific research topics?
Facilitate grant discovery and application processes?
Provide technical review and feedback mechanisms?


Has anyone implemented AI-driven solutions in this space, particularly for:

Automated grant matching?
Research feedback or review processes?
Research community building?


If such platforms exist, what has been your experience with them? What works well and what could be improved?


I'm particularly interested in solutions that support the transition of researchers toward independence and sustainable research careers.

By "remote" do you actually mean "unaffiliated"? Why do you think "AI" is a good solution for this? What do you even mean by "AI"? You've tagged "generative AI" which is entirely unsuited for that. Did you mean to use the [tag:ai] tag?

Before they close your question, can you provide the link to your company, please?

@IvanNepomnyashchikh definitely not that would make this spam and deletable
